# Declare a Typescript function that complies to a type

Tags: typescript, types

Let's suppose I have declared a type containing defining a specific type of function

```
type Callback = (err: Error | null, result: any)
type UselessFunction = (event: string, context: any, callback: Callback) => void
```

I would like to declare functions that must comply to the type `UselessFunction`

I only found in the documentation how to assign a type to a function using arrow syntax

```
const someFunction: UselessFunction = (evt, ctx, cb) => {}
```

How can a type be assigned be function declaration? I cannot find the syntax in the docs

```
function someFunction (event, context, cb) {
}
```

Comment: If you type the individual parameters of `someFunction`, it should gain the type `UselessFunction` where necessary by [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript lacks this functionality. You need to add the type annotation to the declaration's parameters and return value separately to make this function be of a specific type. You can, however, make it a bit more convenient by using [`Parameters`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1464) and [`ReturnType`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1474) types.

```
type UselessFunction = (event: string, context: any, callback: Callback) => void

function someFunction (...params: Parameters<UselessFunction>): ReturnType<UselessFunction> {
  // ...
}
```